# Problem with calculating QGIS Zonal Statistics MEAN

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I need to calculate some zonal statistics from raster files for some polygons in a shapefile. I am using the following code which works:

```
    eligibleLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/usr/Desktop/polygons.shp", "polygons", "ogr")
    for raster in findRasters(windMapsDirectory, '*.tif'):
        (infilepath, infilename) = os.path.split(raster) 
        windMapName = infilename
        list1 = re.split('\W+',windMapName)
        list2 = re.split("_", list1[0])
        list3 = list2[2]
        string1 = ''.join(list3)
        if string1 == 'K':
            zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(eligibleLayer, windMapName, 'K_', 1)
            zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

The problem is that I only need the mean from the zonal statistics (no count and sum). I tried using:

```
        if string1 == 'K':
            zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(eligibleLayer, windMapName, 'K_', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean)
```

However, I get the following error: type object 'QgsZonalStatistics' has no attribute 'Mean' . I am using QGIS 2.8.6.

Comment: Have you tried calling other attributes using this method?

Comment: What happens if you replace `QgsZonalStatistics.Mean` with `zoneStat.Mean`?

Comment: If I replace QgsZonalStatistics.Mean with zoneStat.Mean,  I get: name 'zoneStat' is not defined. Also if I try to call QgsZonalStatistics.Sum, I get: type object 'QgsZonalStatistics' has no attribute 'Sum'

Comment: And if you replace `QgsZonalStatistics.Mean` with `QgsZonalStatistics.Statistic.Mean`?

Comment: I get the same: type object 'QgsZonalStatistics' has no attribute 'Statistic'

Answer (score 3):

For some reason your code is not producing a **QgsZonalStatistics** object. Print 'zoneStats' to corroborate this. It should be observed some similar to:

```
<qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x9fc316ec>
```

I tried out the next code:

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()
provider = layers[1].dataProvider()

path = provider.dataSourceUri()

zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(layers[0], path,"", 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean)

print zoneStat

zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

for this situation:

[image]

and, after running the script, it was added only the mean value; as it can be observed at the next image:

[image]

It works perfectly for me.

Comment: I tried to print out zoneStat after my first condition with the K string and I get:                                                                     <qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x7fc3fc785a68>
<qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x7fc3fc785b00>
<qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x7fc3fc785b00>
<qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x7fc3fc785a68>
<qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x7fc3fc785b00>

Comment: I also compared my result  (with the python script) to the Zonal statistics plugin and I get the same numbers for my polygons...

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I just had the same issue using QGIS 2.14 (`type object 'QgsZonalStatistics' has no attribute 'Mean'`, with a valid `QgsZonalStatistics` object).

It turns out that it works well with QGIS 2.18, so there was probably some change in QGIS API that is not documented, or a bug that was corrected.